# Is it possible to run a logistic regression with NA values in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

The glm function seems to only work if NA values are removed. However, I do not want to remove any data. Is there any way to run a logistic regression with missing values, without changing the data?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can impute missing values. See the [CRAN Task View on missing data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MissingData.html) for many many options. The `mice` package is popular. But generally no, you can't run a model on missing data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to deal with NA values if you do not want do delete the whole row.

It kind of depends on why there is an NA value, for example in a survey the NA could be a non answer which could be an answer in itself, so you could count the NA as its own category.

If the value is missing because of the data collection process, you need to do some data imputation. You could run a simple KNN if you don't want to take to much time creating a model for the inputation.